# Regex to trim html whitespace at end

Tags: php, regex, sql-server-2008, vbscript

A textfield may be padded with combinations of

```
<p></p> 
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<br>
<span></span>
<div></div>
```

and several other variations, including spaces and

I want to remove this, as it screws up the formatting on the web.

I'm thinking of a recursive function which removes trailing 
,   and " ",
then finds the last end-tag, finds the matching start tag, and feeds the contents to itself.
If the returned content is empty, remove the tag.

It could run as a stored procedure in mssqlserver 2008, vbscript (classic asp) or php.

Comment: html should never be treated with regex. never. Use PHP's DOM extension to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a regex, and i think that in this situation the DOM isn't the easyest way. An example with php:

```
$pattern = '~(?><(p|span|div)\b[^>]*+>(?>\s++|&nbsp;)*</\1>|<br/?+>|&nbsp;|\s++)+$~i';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, '', $text);
```

explanations:

```
~
 (?>                          # open an atomic group
     <(p|span|div)\b[^>]*+>   # opening tags, note that this subpattern allows
                              # attributes with [^>]*+ you can remove it if you
                              # don't need it
           (?>\s++|&nbsp;)*   # content allowed inside the tags *

     </\1>                    # closing tag (refer to the first capturing group)
   |                          # OR
     <br/?+>                  # stand alone tag <br>
   |                          # OR
     &nbsp;                   # &nbsp;
   |                          # OR
     \s++                     # white characters
  )+$
~i
```

(*) Note that this pattern doesn't deal with nested tags like: `<div><p></p><\div>` but it is possible to remedy the problem with a recursive pattern:

```
$pattern = '~(<(p|span|div)\b[^>]*+>(?1)*</\2>|<br/?+>|&nbsp;|\s++)+$~i';
```

Here `(?1)` refers to the first capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer is this and doesn't involve complicated regex:

```
$html = str_replace('<span></span>', '' ,$html);
$html = str_replace('<p></p>', '' ,$html);
$html = str_replace('<div></div>', '' ,$html);
```

Replace $html with the string of all your ouput.

Simples!

Comment: This removes tags inside the content too, not just at the end.